# Devise CSS Styling

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, devise

I set up my app with a devise navigation bar which includes my login and register links on the right hand side.  They are horizontal and sized appropriately until I try to style them (to change the font and color only).

I added a span class (to change the font and font color only) and now the join/register links appear stacked vertically rather than horizontally. Does anyone know what needs to be done to get them back to horizontal?

This is my devise span styling:

```
span.deviselinks {
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
  color: white;
    a:link {text-decoration:none; background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:visited {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:hover {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};
    a:active {text-decoration:none;background-color:transparent; color:white;};

}
```

I've used it like this:

```
<span class="deviselinks">
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to('Manage Profile', edit_user_registration_path) %>
  </li>
<% else %>
  <li>
    <%= link_to "Join", "#myRModal", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
  </li>
    </span>
```

This is the segment of my nav bar:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        Hello <%= current_user.first_name %> 
        <%= link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %>
        <% else %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/registration_items" %>
        <%= render "devise/shared/login_items" %>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
```

I tried Max's suggestion with:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <li class="deviselinks">
  <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete) %>       

  </li>
<% else %>
  <li class="deviselinks">

  <%= link_to 'Login', "#myLModal", 'data-toggle' => "modal" %>  
  </li>
```

It doesn't pick up any of the deviselinks styling this way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the bootstrap source, e.g. here: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_navs.scss

It styles `li`s via `.nav > li`, which means the `li` has to be a direct child of your `ul.nav` for bootstrap's styles to apply. So the easiest solution would be to add a `deviselink` class to each of the `li`s instead of wrapping them in a `span`:

```
<!-- span -->
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
    <li class="deviselink">
      <%= link_to('Manage Profile', edit_user_registration_path) %>
    </li>
  <% else %>
    <li class="deviselink">
      <%= link_to "Join", "#myRModal", "data-toggle" => "modal" %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
<!-- /span -->
```

Comment: Hi Max, Thanks for the link. I'm not sure what the suggestion is. Do you mean to put deviselink class around the link in the navbar instead of the registration item itself?

Comment: Sorry, no idea why but I assumed you were using bootstrap. My post has no point if you don't... Share your CSS for the navbar, that'll make it easier to find the problem.

Comment: I am using Bootstrap. I added the navbar section for the devise links

Comment: Oh, in that case my answer should help. I added your snippet and modified it in the way I said.

Comment: Hi Max, thanks I tried it (and updated the above to show the attempt). It doesn't pick up any styling from deviselinks.

Comment: Actually - I forgot to take span out of the div definition. Thanks very much. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to try and add a `float: right` or `left` to your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your bars to be of fixed size? Posting your nav-bar CSS would help. Your font might have changed the boxes' size, which made them not fit in the menu's space horizontally so they get stacked vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You should add links in a div with with both link with float :left then the link will appear horizontally.